# Change icon positions from the command line?

Tags: windows, icons, command-line

Is it possible to use the Windows command line to get or change the positions of icons the screen?

For example, I can drag and move a file's icon on my desktop. How would I retrieve that position from the command line, or any other tool?

Comment: It's funny this was migrated from Stack Overflow, when it's actually almost a duplicate of one of [their own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294116/where-does-the-system-store-the-icons-position). The accepted answer details a registry key (accessible through the command line, but it's.. very hackish) and even links to a sample (GUI) program.